# Unable to access null property of api

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, null

I am using the twitch api. When a channel is offline, I want simply to make the appropriate `<div>` show the string "is currently offline".

According to the [documentation](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/streams/#get-stream-by-user), when a channel is offline

```
{
"stream":null
}
```

Therefore, to make the appropriate div (id=data3) show the string "is currently offline",
I did the following:

```
 if (data.stream == null){

        $( "#data3" ).html( '<a target = "_blank" href ="https://www.twitch.tv/freecodecamp">FreeCodeCamp</a>' +' is currently offline');
      }
```

I am guessing that I did something dumb, but I cannot figure it out.

Here is the full ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/freecodecamp?callback=?',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "callback",
    success: function(data) {
      $( "#data3" ).html('<img src='+ data.stream.channel.logo +'>' +data.stream.channel.display_name+ ' Streaming: ' + data.stream.game +'-- '+ data.stream.channel.status );
      if (data.stream == null){
        $( "#data3" ).html( '<a target = "_blank" href ="https://www.twitch.tv/freecodecamp">FreeCodeCamp</a>' +' is currently offline');
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Test if the stream is `null` *before* trying to access its stream-channel-logo and name (because if the stream is null, those properties won't exist). If the stream is null, set the HTML to the string and return.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/freecodecamp?callback=?',
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonp: "callback",
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.stream == null) {
      $("#data3").html('<a target = "_blank" href ="https://www.twitch.tv/freecodecamp">FreeCodeCamp</a>' + ' is currently offline');
      return;
    }
    $("#data3").html('<img src=' + data.stream.channel.logo + '>' + data.stream.channel.display_name + ' Streaming: ' + data.stream.game + '-- ' + data.stream.channel.status);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data3">

</div>
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! But why wouldn't it try to read properties, fail to do so, and then carryout the "if" statement? Why does failing to read the properties prevent it from executing the if statement?

Comment: Because when a function encounters an error, it immediately stops executing - it doesn't proceed to the next line and hope that everything's fine.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css" >


    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="data3"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slick.min.js"></script> -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

</html>
```

ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/freecodecamp?callback=?',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.stream == null){
            $( "#data3" ).html( '<a target = "_blank" href ="https://www.twitch.tv/freecodecamp">FreeCodeCamp</a>' +' is currently offline');
          }else{
            $( "#data3" ).html('<img src='+ data.stream.channel.logo +'>' +data.stream.channel.display_name+ ' Streaming: ' + data.stream.game +'-- '+ data.stream.channel.status );
          }
      }
    });
```

result

[image]